# Using if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, collision

In this program, the user will be asked to input 2 words, (firstWord and secondWord). The two words will automatically appear on the screen once the object is created.

firstWord is set to change its position on the screen via a while loop.

secondWord will stay in a fixed position.

I want the loop to end once the X position or Y position of firstWord is the same as secondWord.

The XY position of secondWord = (155, 361)

So for instance, something like:

```
if (word1.xPosition = 155) {
    break;
}
```

Obviously, that code is wrong, it is just to give you
an idea of what I want to achieve.
So how would I write this if statement?

My code is pasted below:

```
public words(String w1, String w2)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    firstWord = new Text(w1);
    firstWord.randomizePosition();
    firstWord.changeColor("green");
    firstWord.changeSize(48);
    firstWord.makeVisible();
    secondWord = new Text(w2);
    secondWord.setPosition(155, 361);
    secondWord.changeColor("orange");
    secondWord.changeSize(48);
    secondWord.makeVisible();



public void draw()
{
   while(true) {

    firstWord.randomizePosition();

}    
    if(firstWord.xPosition =  ){

    break;    

}

}
```

Replace the if statement

Comment: It's not clear where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: `while (true)` will never exit. Your app will freeze if you run that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the loop to end once the X position or Y position of firstWord is the same as secondWord

```
while (!( firstWord.getXPosition() == secondWord.getXPosition() || 
          firstWord.getYPosition() == secondWord.getYPosition()) 
{
    firstWord.randomizePosition();
}
```

*"While the first position doesn't equal the second position's X or Y position, change the first position"*

---

If you are expecting to draw these labels on a GUI, don't expect to see any movement without a Thread that redraws the elements between moves.

Comment: `equals()` won't work here, since he wants it to end if *either* X or Y are the same. So he still needs to compare X and Y individually. And I am pretty sure that he wants the stuff to visually update its position on screen and not just show the finished result. So the whole thing would have to be done in a background task that includes a small delay in every iteration of the loop, as well as taking care of performing the updates on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align both elements on EITHER x OR y, you should change your while loop to:

```
while(firstWord's X == secondWord's X || firstWord's Y == secondWord's Y)
  firstWord.randomizePosition();
```

According to your description, this should work. Of course, you can always add a small delay to be able to see the animation, if you want to.

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? I keep getting a compilation error due to the apostrophe in the "firstWord's" and "secondWord's" etc. The compilation error states: "unclosed character literal"

Comment: Oh, I didn't use the actual Java formatting. You need to replace it with something like firstWord.positionX, or firstWord.getPosition.getX(). (Whatever returns the X or Y position of the Object)